# Frustratingly simple jQuery problem

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something very simple in Jquery which i just cant get to fire properly.

The thing is, i'm writing this code in a separate HTML file on the same server and using PHP "include" to use it, the jQuery src is held on Google and referenced in the main index.php head tag.

```
<script src="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#xmasOpen").click(function(){
                $("#xmas").toggleSlide();
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

I've set #xmas to display: none in the CSS but just cant get it to action the jQuery if i click the href with id xmasOpen!?

Anyone?

Comment: Your problem in unclear.

Comment: Any error in js console?

Comment: none. I'm using Firebug and nothing at all

Comment: are you sure you have id #xmas  , or is it a class

Comment: I cant believe everyone (and me) missed this: <script src="text/javascript">
 should be type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method -name  is "[slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)" instead of "toggleSlide" ^^

Answer (score 2):

Move `return false` into the `click` handler.